# My J1 visa expires in less than a month from my intended travel return date from the Schengen area. Will I be issued a visa?

Tags: student-visa, schengen, indian-citizens, h1-visa, j-visa

I am on a J1 visa in the USA. My visa expires at the end of June 2018. I intend to travel to the Schengen area in the first week of June 2018 and come back to the USA within the validity period of my visa. I have valid status in my DS form until 2020. Will I be issued a Schengen visa?

Comment: I don't know whether it matters, but it might: which country's consulate will be handling your application?  I've definitely seen some related questions, but I'm not sure whether they were here or on [Travel.SE].

Comment: i have applied to swiss embassy